# How to show a div on click of an li element using css?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Using CSS, is there any way to show a div which is there inside an li element? i don't wanna use any javascript for this.

here is my sample code for this.

```
<ul>
   <li id="help">
      Help
        <div id="helpContainer">
           This is the help text content
        </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#helpContainer
{
display:none;
}
```

here it is, i wanna display helpContainer div on click of li(id=help)

Comment: You mean you want to use CSS to change what is visible in reaction to a click ? Do you want to be able to hide it with a click ?

Comment: you could use a checkbox with a div inside and a CSS selector for checked and unchecked, but this is best left to javascript... edit: I'm not recommending this.

Comment: @nimi you can do that using :target

Comment: @nimi, please reconsider your Answer and choose the best that helps with your Question. You really didn't give us enough time to code for you. Cheers!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You **must** use Javascript to manipulate the DOM (Document Object Model) of the page.

[This article](http://motyar.blogspot.com/2011/02/handling-onclick-event-with-css.html) describes how to use the #anchor tag coupled with the puesdo-class :target CSS selector (http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-target). This doesn't really do what you want though (you would have to use an anchor tag to hit new # tags to put the page in different states whereas with Javascript you could just assign a listener to the onclick event on the object you actually care about), and I would never use this in practice.

Answer (score 1):

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGRhR/)

Here's a CSS3 method that hides **Help** until it's needed.

To view the hidden **Help**, click the `resize` widget seen at the bottom right corner and drag down vertically.

**CSS3:**

```css
.help{
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  min-height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  max-height: 50px;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.helpContainer {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I am using Chrome on MAC; it is not working. But looks nice trick(via resize)  +1 :)  . Any opinion about my solution?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments. You can use `:target`.

Or if you want to go without `:target` .

```
#helpContainer{  
  float: left;
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 20px;
  top: 10px;
}

#help:active #helpContainer{
  display: block;
}

#helpContainer:hover{
   display: block;
}
```

I made a little demo for that.
http://jsbin.com/eyavuw/1/
(source code) http://jsbin.com/eyavuw/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://html-bin.appspot.com/aghodG1sLWJpbnIMCxIEUGFnZRjJ3kkM) [DEMO2](http://html-bin.appspot.com/aghodG1sLWJpbnIMCxIEUGFnZRjJ3kkM#help) [DEMO3](http://html-bin.appspot.com/aghodG1sLWJpbnIMCxIEUGFnZRiPv0kM)

```
#helpContainer {
  display: none;
}

li#help:hover div#helpContainer{
  display: block;
}
li#help:target div#helpContainer{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: How are you supposed to use that ? It doesn't seem to work on Chrome.

Comment: I've changed the source a bit, notice the url between the two demos. Or a better one: [DEMO](http://html-bin.appspot.com/aghodG1sLWJpbnIMCxIEUGFnZRiPv0kM)

Comment: The first one does nothing for me (Chrome/linux). The second one is just a :hover, this has nothing to see with OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is for styling, so, you can use it to manipulate DOM elements, for that, you will need Javascript.